# Maintain unchecked, checked rows while filtering, sorting and pagination, checked/unchecked rows should be during server side ag grid 2.4.1 angular

Tags: ag-grid-angular

Using AG Grid angular, I want to check/uncheck the rows and check all from header checkbox in ag grid 2.4.1 version, and checked/unchecked rows should be persisted during server side paginaton, filtering and sorting.

On click of header checkbox, All the rows should be selected entire all the pages at once, If i am unchecking any of the rows from the checked rows, The unchecked rows should be persisted. Please help to achieve this using ag grid(2.4.1) angular.

this.columnDefs = [
{
headerName:'',
checkboxSelection: true,
floatingFilter: true,
headerCheckboxSelection: true,
headerComponentFramework: HeaderCheckboxComponent
},
{
//New column def
}
];
This is my column def. HeaderCheckboxComponent is a formatter i was created, but no luck. Please help.